# How do I do this SELECT/OPTION in HTML? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Suppose I have this:

```
<select id="myselect">
<option rel="a">1</option>
<option rel="b">2</option>
<select>
```

How do I use JQuery so that onchange `$("#myselect")`, I alert the "rel" part of the option (not 1 or 2)

Comment: Bear in mind that `rel` is not an attribute of `option`, so this HTML won't validate and this may cause problems in some browsers (going in to Quirks mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr("rel"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
$("myselect").change(function(){
  $(this).children("option:selected").each(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('rel');
          });
});
```

Should work for multiple selects, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    $("#myselect option:selected").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('rel'));
    });
});
```

Just to mention, my code will also work if you have the `multiple="multiple"` attribute on your `SELECT` element, alerting both values.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rel' attribute is not supported on an option element, you should be using the 'value' attribute to specify a value for your options. I'm sure jQuery can fetch that much easier than an unsupported attribute.